# Closing tag for element '<?>' was not found

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on WPF Project. But there is an error showing when I was working on xaml which is "Closing tag for element '`<Style>`' was not found.". Unfortunately I couldn't where I missed the Closing tag. Visual Studio 2012 is showing the error Line and Column. But when I go through there I couldn't see any that I missed closing tag for element '`<Style>`':

[image]

Even though it shows error, it's working without any Exception.

And also my all TabIndex-s are looks disordered, everytime I pressed enter.

Comment: Could you share more information, possibly your XAML? Probably it's as plain as simple as some small error in the XAML. Furthermore, error Line and Column in the error are not always trustworthy...

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth I wanted to post some image. Could you please do it on behalf of me?

Comment: @mangasm, add a link to the online image and then users with enough reputation will add it as an image to your post.

Comment: I know it's a plain and simple error. But my XAML file is too big and untfortunately I couldn't show them fully. Please see the image from here http://s12.postimg.org/hu2l28xod/Untitled.png

Comment: try to check it by using region symbols in xaml on left hand side..may be somewhere you find that you will not able to close it..you can only solve this problem as your xaml is too big :)

Comment: Did you try a rebuild all? Close and re-open VS?

Comment: Can you upload your code to something like dropbox? We can then have a look...

Comment: CLEAN-REBUILD or RESTART-REBUILD the Solution. This was the SOLUTION! Hope this post will be necessary to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right click on solution -> **Clean**, than **Rebuild** or even better **restart VS** and than **Rebuild**